# Stargazer: changing line style

Tags: latex, stargazer

Is is possible to change line style in stargazer table in Rstudio, or does one need to change if "by-hand" in latex source code:

for example:

```
library(stargazer)
library(dplyr)


mtcars[1:10, ] %>% 
  stargazer(type = "text", summary = F)
```

if I want last line to be double line, do I have to change it in latex code or can it be done in Rstudio?

Comment: By default, it's only possible to adjust this for regression models: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816597/stargazer-line-type there seems to be no option for summary statistics.